# Can I have some criticism?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I'm talking about SO, one of the best sites I've ever known.

There are some things I wanted to ask, and learn what others (especially gurus and the owners) think about this point of view.

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) caused me to be banned.

1. I do not want to ask you to give my account back.
2. Most of the people here are not native English speakers, so a few misunderstandings and misleading topics are possible.
3. Aren't we sometimes treating the users cruel, harsh, or too bossy?
4. 1. I've been a developer for more than 16 years and had different experiences, maybe in some expert and if we summarize the subjects I will be quite good.
   2. Developers could have different opinions about sharing their code and ideas.
      So, if I didn't post a piece of my commercial code, can I be blamed for that?
      In some posts I tried to summarize the code as much as I can.
   3. Sometimes explaining a question is hard, or explaining why and when you come into that problem could be hard also.

      In some of my posts the confusion comes when you started 2-3 pieces of new coding technologies.
   4. I myself Google first before each of my posts,
      then maybe someone will come into your topic and give their own Googled links, 
      or believe me sometimes you will get silly or irrelevant answers.

      So if one time I asked "please give a piece of code regarding my simple problem" that was the reason. And, a person came to that topic looking at it upside-down saying, "don't ask for code! What have you done?" In that case I did a similar activity in 4-5 different ways if I posted a key part about each the topic would be messed-up and that would cause just confusion, and some others maybe came to talk about other different parts of that topic. Isn't it right?
   5. Being more in SO could be good because I love this site, but having more reputation here doesn't mean that someone is higher than anyone or even has more knowledge on the topic, but it's possible to be true that way, maybe lots of the higher ranks have more free time than some others!
5. I like SO a lot and think it could be the best site on the globe and this is one of the sites I was spending more of my time on the Web here.
6. Sometimes you have to give your question in the simplest form that it comes into your mind. There are situations when you are in a hurry and your question isn't as good well-formed as you desire.
7. Maybe 2 questions be completely relevant and complementary to each other,
   and be better to be in one question and not separates into 2 different questions.
8. I think some times moderators that want to manage and control the topics and trying to reform 
   SO's posts and making them more reliable with rules do taking decisions with precipitation.

These were my ideas or some notions that came into my mind regarding these kinds of problem
and maybe a bit of criticism that some could be thought about.

Comment: Ummm... what's that, now?

Comment: You might want to re-phrase the title...

Comment: "*No problem if the post been edited, cause didn't review it*" - Um.  Low quality questions (that you haven't reviewed before posting) would also factor into the question ban, FYI o_O

Comment: @Ben I actually kind of liked the title, as someone who likes getting constructive criticism, myself. But once I hit the *content* of this post... erm... ;)

Comment: This isn't a low quality question, I tried to form it the best to have the whole key parts I wanted to mention, haven't more time to spend on this, I as a webmaster always will like people to give their opinions on the site and personal point of views, so the website could consider it or not, this isn't a problem for the one who gives his opinions

Comment: @Sypress some of it isn't even a question. Most of your points under #4 are observations or statements.

Comment: Well, posting something on Meta that is bound to be closed as "not a real question" is a perfect way to prove that the ban on SO was justified... (that means, even if you ignore the "I didn't bother to think, feel free to edit for me" part)

Comment: @Andrew Barber, I saw the +1 before a loop for the negative marks !, What do you think is wrong with the topic I started ?

Comment: @Sypress You make a bunch of statements, most of which aren't really a question. It's hard to understand what you're aiming at.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant  , there wasn't any place else let you give your critism, I thought Meta is for that, anyway it's tagged with Discussion ?!!

Comment: @Sypress: You need to ask questions, even on Meta - Stack Overflow isn't built for empty chat. Even a discussion needs to be constructive, for that there must be a clear problem to solve. So far you totally failed to point out any.

Comment: @vcsjones the only comment that tried to give me an information which could help me find a problem within the post, I think this is again like what I said before, I didn't even wanted to give a single statement, maybe used some "English Words" incorrectly. e.g : Developers could have different opinions ... is it a statement in your language ? :D, Don't know really when it causes some negative results , so the post is in incorrect format.

Comment: @Sypress I'm having real trouble understanding you at all. I don't know how many people are voting to close, but in an effort to help: is there a question you can boil this down to?

Comment: @Wladimir Palant I see, but if any user of my owned sites give me his/her opinion, It will be constructive for me, anyway didn't know that in the closed topic reference here was told talk in the chatroom about it, but in the chat also wasn't a place for this issue, I think this problem could be happened for others also, these were just things I wanted to ask others opinions about it, but again seems that couldn't explain the problem itself correctly.

Comment: @simchona I wanted to tag you the same time as Wladimir, cause both of you mentioned the same thing, didn't get really the phrase you used, if you meant the link to the question caused me banned, the link was included in the first paragraph of the topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868960/an-async-task-issue-cross-threaded-access-to-forms, thanks for trying to understand me :D

Comment: For the most part, we honestly can't tell what your *opinions* are, let alone what questions you might be asking. I think you're just trying to defend your posting style on SO. It seems to me that you must understand the correct way to post, but instead you're trying to defend your right to post the *wrong* way. Instead, why not put that energy into trying to learn and follow the community standards? If you think SO is so great, then you must realize it is those standards that *make* it great.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill I understand, really the standards and being quality-based cause a site like SO to stay at top, a piece of blame should be for me that I didn't spend the time you said to learn more about posting, I'm about 3 years in SO with just about 20 questions, I had quite good respect for most of my posts, a silver badge, more than 3k views for one the other,and more (in just 20 questions), Yes, I tried to defend my point of views but as you mentioned described wrongly

Comment: @Ben I think you have changed the meaning of point 3 though? I think it should have read "Aren't we treating the users"... otherwise, nice edit.

Comment: @Bart, quite possibly. I tried to add sense ( and couldn't always think of a way of doing it). Please feel free to change it!

Comment: As an aside, *if* all works well, then it's never a single question that gets one banned. (But of course, something trips the balance.)

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this. In part, it's because I'm having a difficult time understanding you. But mostly it's because you don't seem to have a single central point or question, just a list of loosely related observations. I see that you're still editing, so I won't interfere with edits of my own, but if you want to cover multiple topics, it might help you to post one question for each.

Comment: You deleted a crapton of your own questions/answers, mostly for no (obvious) good reason.  I've undeleted many.  If you have answered them yourself, try adding an answer and accepting it in order to close out the question.  Users with low reps and many deleted questions/answers get autobanned.

Comment: @Popular Demand  you have the right man, I see, just pointed everything related to the subject from my point of view, that was a piece of critism from the past 3 years I had with SO

Comment: @ Won't I deleted just a line, usually I edit my posts in any time after the post to correct it or after a review

Comment: @Won't is talking about your questions on SO. You have deleted a fair amount of those apparently.

Comment: @Bart Yes, I forgot that to mention, maybe this could be a subject for some negative votes, but I was talking about it here in a different way, Doesn't the owner of a question have the right to delete it when no one is participated in ? or even if you think that your question had a problem, or again didn't have enough time to consider that question ? or when you got just an answer which it was really off-topic ? Don't know is it good or bad ?

Comment: Seriously tempted to edit with extreme prejudice and boil this down to the two or three questions that are buried amongst the swathe of observation.

Comment: @Wont, sorry at first I didn't get you, So the problem was the deletion of some of my posts, I will review them in a possible time, thanks for that

Comment: *"Can I have some criticism? [closed]" -10 points*. No you can't. Thou shalt offend the stack overlords!

Answer (score 10):

> Most of the people here are not English native speakers, so a few misunderstandings and misleading topics are possible.

Non English speakers of course are welcome. However, StackOverflow is an English site, so if you want to participate, a certain degree of command of the English language is required. There are [many proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french) on Area51 of StackOverflow in a different language. If you feel that your language skills are a barrier to effective participation in StackOverflow, find one in your language, or propose one.

> Aren't the users sometimes cruel or harsh, or too bossy? "Do this! Don't do that!"

Perhaps the interpretation of "bossy" might be part of your first point, which is language barrier. We are communicating through a very inexpressive medium, simple text. You can't gauge tone and mood from text alone, at least not very well. Text should be taken for what it is. Trying to extract feelings and anger from it almost always leads to misunderstanding.

There is a degree of "you should be doing this", and "you really shouldn't be doing that" mainly because the community feels that adhering to those things ultimately helps it. StackOverflow *is* an awesome community, and the content and help you receive is outstanding. The strict standards that are in place are what helped make it that way. Many other communities have no such standards, and posts like "Can u help me with X plz?" cause that community to suffer.

> Sometimes explaining a question is hard, or explaining why and when you come into that problem could be hard also.

Do your best. If more clarification is needed, it will usually be asked for in comments. Edit your question and improve it until it supplies enough information to be answerable. If the question is hard, then maybe the question is too big and should be asked in smaller, more appropriately sized questions.

> Developers could have different opinions about sharing their code and ideas. So, if I didn't post a piece of my commercial code, can I be blamed for that? In some posts I tried to summarize the code as much as I can.

If you don't want to share your code, then don't. However that isn't a reason to believe that an answer that *doesn't answer the question* is any more acceptable. You could create a more contrived example of your commercial code that is different enough to not be considered the same thing.

> I myself Google first before each of my posts, then maybe someone will come into your topic and give their own Googled links, or believe me sometimes you will get silly or irrelevant answers.

Then don't vote it up, or at least leave a comment explaining that you have seen the link and it wasn't able to help you.

> So if one time I asked "please give a piece of code regarding my simple problem" that was the reason. And, a person came to that topic looking at it upside-down saying, "don't ask for code! What have you done?" In that case I did a similar activity in 4-5 different ways if I posted a key part about each the topic would be messed-up and that would cause just confusion, and some others maybe came to talk about other different parts of that topic. Isn't it right?

Don't ask for a full solution then. If you are having problems finding the right way to get started, then that is what you should ask for. Ask for a pointer, or a place to start, or pseudo code. At the very least, if you have made an effort, show it.

> Sometimes you have to give your question in a simplest form that it comes into your mind, there are situations that you are on hurry and your question isn't as good well-formed as you desire.

If you aren't going to make the required effort to make it a good question, *then don't ask it*. Rushed or not, questions need to be good. That includes explaining what you are looking for, what you have tried, what it doesn't work, etc. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sure that your answer is a quality answer although my question was not a good one based on the upper comments, Also I have to read my question again cause of some helpful edits, will read and answer if possible during the day, for the first part just I can say maybe I be good at English specially with more concentration and when be relaxed more and not in a such hurry that now every time I have,

Comment: but don't want to say that this is right, I agree with you, In other hand when you weren't native speaker and try to improve yourself to be perfect on this case, maybe you use a larger circle of words and try to form them in different kind of situations, specially as a piece of my problem maybe I don't know lots of equivalent good formal words for my writings, or maybe I refactored some sentences to save time and again that would cause a piece of misunderstanding that people will think that I was giving some statements :DD, sorry for that !

Comment: The viability of [non-english SOs is dubious at best.](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable) 4 of the 9 proposals have been deleted and with the exception of Turkish (at 91%) it doesn't look like the remaining will get out of the commitment phase

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Possibly, but at least turning attention to them may help them.

Answer (score 8):

There's quite a lot of things in your question but two points in particular I wanted to pick up on:

> Developers could have different opinions about sharing their code and ideas. So, if I didn't post a piece of my commercial code, can I be blamed for that? In some posts I tried to summarize the code as much as I can.

The best thing to do regardless of if it's real commercial code, a hobby project or a text book exercise is to create a minimal but complete example of the problem. That way you don't reveal your secrets, but more importantly you give everyone who might be able to answer it a common, unambiguous starting point to answer from.

Usually you'd want to explain what what your example does and why you weren't expecting that or what you were trying to make it do.

From a complete but minimal example I can run it on my machine and see the error you got or the results very easily and try out ideas for fixing it without having to spend a lot of time recreating what you describe. If 10 people each create a minimal example to try it out that's a huge waste of effort for something you could very easily have supplied with the question.

As an added bonus often the cause of the problem becomes obvious when you're creating a minimal but complete example - either it doesn't work in your minimal test case (in which case your assumptions were wrong) or you spot how to fix it in the process.

> There are situations when you are in a hurry and your question isn't as good well-formed as you desire

If you're in a hurry the best way to make sure you get good answers quickly is to spend some time making the question as unambiguous, clear and well formatted as possible - so anyone who might know the answer can glance at it decide quickly that they want to answer.

Comment: tried a +1 with no effect ...

Comment: @awoodland, a [short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/)? A fine post +1.

Comment: @Ben - my thoughts exactly (although until SO I'd always called it a MWE - minimal working example). I didn't reference that and tried to explain it in my own words to avoid jargonising it though, which I think might be useful in this instance.